# Why does subscribe work and block doesn't in Spring reactive Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I created a project fresh out of the [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) by choosing `Kotlin`, `Gradle`, `M7` and `Web-reactive`.

I made a small project:

```
data class Person (val id: String)

@Component class PersonHandler(val template: ReactiveMongoTemplate) 
{
    init
    {
        println("Initializing")

        val jim: Mono<Person> =  template.save(Person("Jim"))
        val john: Mono<Person> = template.save(Person("John"))
        val jack: Mono<Person> = template.save(Person("Jack"))

        launch(jim)
        launch(john)
        launch(jack)

        println("Finished Initializing")
    }

    fun launch(mono: Mono<Person>)
    {
        mono.subscribe({println(it.id)}, {println("Error")}) // This works
        // mono.block()  This just hangs
    } 
}
```

I try to save three persons into the database. The `save` method returns just a `Mono` which needs to be executed. If I try to execute it by simply subscribing, everything works nice:

```
Initializing
Finished Initializing
2017-12-21 13:14:39.513  INFO 17278 --- [      Thread-13] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:158}] to localhost:27017
2017-12-21 13:14:39.515  INFO 17278 --- [      Thread-12] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:159}] to localhost:27017
2017-12-21 13:14:39.520  INFO 17278 --- [      Thread-14] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:160}] to localhost:27017
Jim
Jack
John
```

However, when I use `block` instead of `subscribe` the application hangs:

```
Initializing
2017-12-21 13:16:47.200  INFO 17463 --- [      Thread-14] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:163}] to localhost:27017
```

If I query the database manually, I see that **Jim** has been saved, but not Jack and John.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? I would like to have the guarantee that the users are in the database before the code goes any further so I would really like to use `block`.

I am not sure if it is relevant, but I get a compiler warning

> Accessing nonfinal property `template` in constructor

There is a minimal working example. It contains two branches. One is a workaround for the issue.

https://github.com/martin-drozdik/spring-mongo-bug-example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this might be a Spring Framework bug / usability issue.

First, let me underline the difference between `subscribe` and `block`:

- the `subscribe` method kicks off the work and returns immediately. So you get no guarantee that the operation is done when other parts of your application run.
- `block` is a blocking operation: it triggers the operation and waits for its completion.

For initialisation work, composing operations and calling block once is probably the best choice:

```
val jim: Mono<Person> =  template.save(Person("Jim"))
val john: Mono<Person> = template.save(Person("John"))
val jack: Mono<Person> = template.save(Person("Jack"))
jim.then(john).then(jack).block();
```

As you've stated, using `block` hangs the application. I suspect this might be an Spring context initialisation issue - If I remember correctly, this process might assume a single thread in some parts and using a reactive pipeline there schedules work on many threads.

Could you create a minimal sample application (using just Java/Spring Boot/Spring Data Reactive Mongo) and report that on https://jira.spring.io?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I already opened an issue on Github https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11438#issuecomment-354259225 with a MWE on https://github.com/martin-drozdik/spring-mongo-bug-example (also with a workaround branch) but it was closed. The developers told me it is sufficient to have it on SO. Should I post it on Jira instead?

Comment: Yes I think this is a Spring Framework issue, not a Spring Boot one. So the Jira link I gave you should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar situation where by calling "reactiveMongoTemplate.save(model).**block()**" the application was hanging.

The issue was caused by the @PostConstruct in one of my classes designed to create my system users after the application initialization. I think somehow It was invoked before full Spring context initialization.

```
@Configuration
public class InitialDataPostLoader  {
    private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        logger.info(String.format(MSG_SERVICE_JOB, "System Metadata initialization"));
        createDefaultUsers();
    }
```

By replacing @PostConstruct with ContextRefreshEvent listener the issues got resolved.

```
@Configuration 
public class InitialDataPostLoader implements
 ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
     private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());

     @Override
     public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent arg0) {

         logger.info(String.format(MSG_SERVICE_JOB, "System Metadata initialization"));
         createDefaultUsers();

     }
```

Comment: I don't think this relates to the question at matter, but has solved my issue.